# Are two identical sets each other's subsets / supersets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given two sets:

> $a = \{1,2,3\} $
>
> $b=\{1,2,3\}$

Are they supersets of each other? Are they subsets of each other?

Comment: Every set is a subset of itself.

Comment: @BabakSorouh and a superset of itself?

Comment: Yes! They are superset of itself.

Comment: Yes, subset and superset. But neither *proper* subset nor *proper* superset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the definition of subset? Of superset? It shouldn't be difficult to prove that a set is a subset and superset of itself. Actually, two sets $A$ and $B$ are identical *if and only if* $A$ is both a subset and superset of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it is a quite trivial consequence of the definition of the notion of a subset that if $a = b$ then $a \subset b$ and $b \subset a$.

But also do note that it is a bit unhappy to say 'given *two* sets' here when you've given two different labels to *one and the same* set!